# Remembering user action using cookies

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm working on a "this site uses cookies" message to show the user when they go on the index page of the site.

I want the user to be able to dismiss the message, and the browser should remember, so it isn't displayed again when the user reloads the page.

I'm using Laravel, and I've looked into storing variables in the session,
but the request doesn't go through a controller to get to the index view.

When the user clicks the button, the message should disappear without reloading.

Comment: Use JavaScript to dismiss the message and set a cookie.

Comment: you can use the cookie or browser local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done only with Javascript, without going over the server, in the onclick event of your button, call a function with code of creating a cookie or storing a value in Localstorage of the browser :

- Code to create cookie with JS :

```
document.cookie = "accept=true";
```

- Code to create value in localStorage :

```
localStorage.setItem('accept', 'true');
```

- And then try to get the value from cookie or local storage like this :
- Cookies :

```
var x = document.cookie;
//document.cookie will return all cookies in one string much like: cookie1=value; cookie2=value; cookie3=value;
```

- LocalStorage :

```
var accept = window.localStorage.getItem('accept');
if(!accept)
    {
      ....................
    }
```